# Jersey and Tomcat "HTTP 404 The requested resource is not available."

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey

I was receiving the `HTTP 404 The requested resource is not available.` error for a while and I could not figure out what was wrong until I changed my maven dependencies for Jersey from:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

which I pulled from someone's project, to this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

which then my application started working fine. What is the difference between these Jersey dependencies and is there a way to debug whether or not the `404` was caused by an incorrect annotation, web.xml configuration, or a missing jar?

I am using Hibernate + Tomcat + Jersey. This isn't the complete `pom.xml` but the Jersey dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
<artifactId>Example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <jersey.version>2.14</jersey.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- ******* Hibernate ******* -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ******* Jersey ******* -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ******* jTDS ******* -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you provide a bit more details about your setup, you are using tomcat + spring + jersey - I am bit confused with the exclusions and inclusions. It would help of you provide some more info.

Comment: So seems as though it's because Tomcat doesn't support jax-rs. Is that right? How can a newcomer to web development in Java know whether it is a missing dependency or something wrong with the resource path?

Comment: Can you post you pom ?

Comment: What does tomcat output when it's trying to deploy your web app?

Comment: The pom.xml shown works as expected. But when The Jersey dependency is substituted with the glassfish dependencies, it does not work and throws `HTTP 404` error.

Comment: 1. How are you configuring your application? web.xml? Java config? 2. You still need `jersey-container-servlet`

Comment: @peeskillet what dependencies should I use? This is frustrating since the application now isn't working from yesterday even though nothing was changed.